Proving Property $(P)$ and the divergence characterization for open connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I am studying a property $(P)$ of open subsets $\Omega$  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , defined as follows:
An open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ has property $ (P) $ if, for every $ \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ (the space of smooth functions with compact support in $ \Omega $) such that $ \int_{\Omega} \varphi(x) dx = 1 $, and for every $ u \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega) $, there exists $ v \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n) $ such that:
$$
u = \operatorname{div} v + \varphi \int_{\Omega} u(x) dx,
$$
where $ \operatorname{div} v = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i} $.
I am trying to solve the following questions:

Prove that any open connected set $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ has property $(P)$. Additionally, $ v $ can be chosen to depend continuously on $u$ and $\varphi$
The idea seems to involve decomposing $\Omega $ into smaller subsets (e.g., rectangles) for which $(P)$ is easier to verify, and then extending the result to $ \Omega $ using partitions of unity and connectedness. However even when studying the case just for $\Omega = (0,1)^n$, I am unable to construct a $v$ that solves the problem.

Could someone provide a detailed and rigorous explanation of these steps? Any references to relevant methods or theorems would also be appreciated.

Edited to respect guidelines. Thanks!

In a more fancy language what you considered is a version of Poincaré lemma (with compact supports) on $n$ forms: $u$ and $\vec v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ are identified with $udx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$ and $v=v_1dx_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge dx_n+\dots+v_ndx_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge dx_{n-1}$, where $\operatorname{div}\vec v=dv$.
All of your questions have answer yes. If you keep track of the proof in say Theorem 2.4 of Zuoqin Wang's lecture notes on The de Rham Cohomology with Compact Supports you get a continuous inverse.

Thank you for pointing out the connection to the Poincaré lemma and Zuoqin Wang's notes! I’ll explore this further and will update with a more detailed response if I work out a rigorous proof.
